# Migrate Post action to web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have an Action on MVC Application and I need to do the same thing but in a application that uses Web Forms. I'm sorry if this is such a stupid thing but I'm not to expert on web forms.

This is my Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string userName)
{

}
```

How do I do the HttpPost in a web form?

**UPDATE**

I discovered if I put this (Page.Request["login"]) in my code I'm able to retrieve all post parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use the [HttpWebPost Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)class.

Something like

```
   private void OnPostInfoClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       string strId = UserId_TextBox.Text;
       string strName = Name_TextBox.Text;

       ASCIIEncoding encoding=new ASCIIEncoding();
       string postData="userid="+strId;
       postData += ("&username="+strName);
       byte[]  data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

       // Prepare web request...
        HttpWebRequest myRequest =
        (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/Default.aspx");
        myRequest.Method = "POST";
        myRequest.ContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
        Stream newStream=myRequest.GetRequestStream();

        // Send the data.
        newStream.Write(data,0,data.Length);
        newStream.Close();
   }
```

Comment: Thank you. I used it to simulate a post redirect.